# Expansion Mechanism in Loop Quantum Gravity

Tags: loop-quantum-gravity

Loop Quantum Gravity suggests that spacetime is quantized.  Given that, what is the mechanism of expansion?  Do more quanta appear out of nowhere or do the quanta grow larger?